# Angular2 Update View on async model update

Tags: angular

I've got a Angular2 component with dependency on a datastore.
Template has some databinding on that store, e.g. "{{datastore.weather.curTemp}}"
Datastore get's updated from time to time via http.

Now i understand that this works in an asnyc way - which is the cause my curTemp get's not updated automatically when new data arrives, right?

My current solution would be to use an EventEmitter to notify my component on changes, but then I would need either a local variable to bind to, which could get messy, if I need a lot of variables from my datastore, or I would call detectChanges() on ChangeDetectorRef.

Am I on the right track? Or am I missing a simple way of populating my asny-data?

Thank you!

Comment: have you tried async pipe  https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html

Comment: That would mean simply expose my variables as Observables, right? Sounds promising thank you !  - UPDATE: Tried that, but it does not update my view :(

Answer (score 1):

If your component is not updating, perhaps your async thread is running outside the NgZone, and you might need to update your component by making the assignment inside the component's *NgZone*.

```
import {Component, NgZone} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})

export class MyComponent {
  myValue: string;

  constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {
  }

  getData() {
    const self = this;
    myAsyncCall().then(result => {
      ngZone.run(() => {
        self.myValue = result;
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to solve your problem would be to make `weather` a `Subject`:

datastore.service.ts

```
public weather: Subject<any> = new Subject(); // better make this private and expose it `asObservable` via a getter nethod

updateWeather(){
  http.get(...).subscribe(res => this.weather.next(res.json()))
}
```

You could then get a reference to that in your component.ts:

```
public weather$: Observable<any>;
constructor (dataStore: DataStore){
  this.weather$ = dataStore.weather;
}
```

And use it in your template like this:

```
{{(weather$ | async).curTemp}}
```

That way you also don't need to handle subscriptions when your component is destroyed as the async pipe does it for you.

Comment: It's really weird: If I keep reloading my page, every x times binding work's as intended.. the rest of the time it does not get updated.... ?

Comment: My errors were due to some really weird stuff... see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39057644/angular2-view-not-updated-when-using-setinterval?noredirect=1#comment65467196_39057644

Comment: Won't this create a subscription to that observable everytime you use `(weather$ | async)` in the template? Seems like that could be wasteful vs subscribing in the component and updating some component state in a single subscription.