# Angular2 View not updated when using setInterval

Tags: angular

I am using Angular2 RC5 - and I have a strange problem.
In my main component I use for testing purposes in my constructor:

```
 setInterval(() => {
        this.test = new Date().getMilliseconds().toString();           
    }, 500);
```

Binding in my template is

```
<p>{{test}}</p>
```

Upon loading or reloading the page it either displays a value (but does not change on further ticks), somtimes it works as intended (updates value on every tick), and sometimes just displays the initial value and does not change at all. Seems random.

I get crazy over this, as it seems in the official plunker version it works without a problem. (Edit: [Plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/CXscxmt6VWM3Dwlzztsj?p=info) )

I get the same behaviour when using this code in other components aswell..

Anyone any idea?

Comment: Try doing this in ngOnInit instead as a standard. that's the best practice anyway especially for unit testing as you do not need to remember any variable dependencies to just create your component. Let me know if this helps at all. It does seem weird.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that.. it did not help .. I even deleted es6-shim from my polyfills.ts (webpack), as I read about the loading order could cause some trouble.. but that did not work either.. :(

Comment: You could use `Observable.interval()` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this, This worked fine for me.

> import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

```
Observable.interval(500)
    .subscribe(() => {
    this.test = new Date().getMilliseconds().toString();    
})
```

Comment: Thanks, that would be another  way to do it. But at the time I wrote that question it was really a bug with fontawesome. I don't know if it has been fixed by now as i switched from fontawesome to material icons by that time.

Comment: Okay, But I was having same problem with setInterval, It works better with Observable.interval(). Mark correct, someone might get answer they are looking for.. like me :)

Comment: Although this is an alternative way of doing `setInterval`, I don't think this is the correct answer. For me it was a problem elsewhere in my code that was causing a memory leak that slowed the DOM from being updated (similar to what @Mr.Muh mentioned)

Answer (score 0):

I know this sounds crazy, but the moment I 
comment out

```
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/f0298bc7e9.js"></script>
```

in my index.html everything works. I don't know why or how...
It just seems to be the reason for that. With the line: Strange behavior. Without: Everything works.
To make it even more strange: I **cannot** reproduce that on the "official" plunker...